# How to implement a Future or Stream that polls an async fn?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, future, unsafe

I have a struct `Test` I want to implement `std::future::Future` that would poll `function`:

```rust
use std::{
    future::Future,
    pin::Pin,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};

struct Test;

impl Test {
    async fn function(&mut self) {}
}

impl Future for Test {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match self.function() {
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Ready(_) => Poll::Ready(()),
        }
    }
}
```

That didn't work:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:17:13
   |
10 |     async fn function(&mut self) {}
   |                                  - the `Output` of this `async fn`'s expected opaque type
...
17 |             Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `Poll`
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl Future`
                     found enum `Poll<_>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:18:13
   |
10 |     async fn function(&mut self) {}
   |                                  - the `Output` of this `async fn`'s expected opaque type
...
18 |             Poll::Ready(_) => Poll::Ready(()),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `Poll`
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl Future`
                     found enum `Poll<_>`
```

I understand that `function` must be called once, the returned `Future` must be stored somewhere in the struct, and then the saved future must be polled. I tried this:

```rust
struct Test(Option<Box<Pin<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>);

impl Test {
    async fn function(&mut self) {}
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut s = Self(None);
        s.0 = Some(Box::pin(s.function()));
        s
    }
}
```

That also didn't work:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Future<Output = ()> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/lib.rs:7:13
    |
7   | struct Test(Option<Box<Pin<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Future<Output = ()> + 'static)`
```

After I call `function()` I have taken a `&mut` reference of `Test`, because of that I can't change the `Test` variable, and therefore can't store the returned `Future` inside the `Test`.

I did get an unsafe solution (inspired by [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rustjerk/comments/g0o9rb/fighting_the_borrow_checker/))

```rust
struct Test<'a>(Option<BoxFuture<'a, ()>>);

impl Test<'_> {
    async fn function(&mut self) {
        println!("I'm alive!");
    }

    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut s = Self(None);
        s.0 = Some(unsafe { &mut *(&mut s as *mut Self) }.function().boxed());
        s
    }
}

impl Future for Test<'_> {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        self.0.as_mut().unwrap().poll_unpin(cx)
    }
}
```

I hope that there is another way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though there are times when you may want to do things similar to what you're trying to accomplish here, they are a rarity. So most people reading this, maybe even OP, may wish to restructure such that struct state and data used for a single async execution are different objects.

To answer your question, yes it is somewhat possible. Unless you want to absolutely resort to unsafe code you will need to use [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html). All fields you wish to manipulate inside the `async fn` will have to be wrapped inside a `Mutex` and the function itself will accept an `Arc<Self>`.

I must stress, however, that this is not a beautiful solution and you probably don't want to do this. Depending on your specific case your solution may vary, but my guess of what OP is trying to accomplish while using `Stream`s would be better solved by something similar to [this gist that I wrote](https://gist.github.com/TimLuq/83a35453405f4c6e0f63fb2a0caa9f6e).

```rust
use std::{
    future::Future,
    pin::Pin,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

struct Test {
    state: Mutex<Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>>,
    // if available use your async library's Mutex to `.await` locks on `buffer` instead
    buffer: Mutex<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Test {
    async fn function(self: Arc<Self>) {
        for i in 0..16u8 {
            let data: Vec<u8> = vec![i]; // = fs::read(&format("file-{}.txt", i)).await.unwrap();
            let mut buflock = self.buffer.lock().unwrap();
            buflock.extend_from_slice(&data);
        }
    }
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Self> {
        let s = Arc::new(Self {
            state: Default::default(),
            buffer: Default::default(),
        });

        {
            // start by trying to aquire a lock to the Mutex of the Box
            let mut lock = s.state.lock().unwrap();
            // create boxed future
            let b = Box::pin(s.clone().function());
            // insert value into the mutex
            *lock = Some(b);
        } // block causes the lock to be released

        s
    }
}

impl Future for Test {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(
        self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>,
        ctx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<<Self as std::future::Future>::Output> {
        let mut lock = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        let fut: &mut Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>> = lock.as_mut().unwrap();
        Future::poll(fut.as_mut(), ctx)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Mutex::lock` is blocking

Comment: @AndreaNardi in general `std::sync::Mutex` is blocking, yes. In this example, however, it will never actually be blocked since it is a private field and each mutex is only accessed in one place at a time.
So in this specific case the Mutex will never block and basically acts like a safe version of an `AtomicPtr` (with some extra overhead).

Comment: > this gist that I wrote.

Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Is it possible to do the same but without boxing future(s) in `item_state`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve and why, but I suspect that you're trying to implement `Future for Test` based on some ancient tutorial or misunderstanding and just overcomplicating things.

You don't have to implement `Future` manually. An `async` function

```rust
async fn function(...) {...}
```

is really just syntax sugar translated behind the scenes into something like

```rust
fn function(...) -> Future<()> {...}
```

All you have to do is to use the result of the function the same way as any future, e.g. use await on it or call block a reactor until it's finished. E.g. based on your first version, you can simply call:

```rust
let mut test = Test{};
test.function().await;
```

UPDATE1

Based on your descriptions I still think you're trying to overcomplicate this minimal working snippet without the need to manually implement `Future` for anything:

```rust
async fn asyncio() { println!("Doing async IO"); }

struct Test {
    count: u32,
}

impl Test {
    async fn function(&mut self) {
        asyncio().await;
        self.count += 1;
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut test = Test{count: 0};
    test.function().await;
    println!("Count: {}", test.count);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement `futures::Stream`, and I want to shove the code from `poll_next` into different `async fn(&mut self)` functions.

`futures::Stream::poll_next` is basically the same as `Future::poll`, but I can note that in the question

Comment: Unless you're writing a low level async lib like `async-std`, you are not supposed to manually implement `Future` or `Stream` yourself. You should just use the futures (e.g. TCP connect) and streams (e.g. TCP stream bytes) returned by those libs and use combinators like `map()` for processing their results.
Do you really need something else here?

Comment: I'm trying to implement an interface for a WebSocket API, using `tokio-tungstenite`, with `Stream` and `Sink` (i don't have any problems with the latter). That API has a lot of useless and sometimes incomplete messages. I can in theory implement everything with `filter_map` or something like that and a LOT of states, but it'll probably be even messier than it is now.

Comment: Ok, now at least your environment is clear. I hope you're using `tokio_tungstenite` and not the plain blocking `tungstenite`.
Sorry, but I'm not familiar with these libs and can't afford too much time here. Your exact problem is still nearly impossible to be solved without a lot of more details, preferrably a minimized reproducible example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that example in the OP is pretty much all I need - implement a `Future` (or a `Stream`, which is basically the same), that calls an `async fn` that takes `&mut self`. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. ;-) What I was trying to explain is that you don't have to implement a `Future` for an `async fn` because the `async fn` is already a `Future` itself.