# Why is an async fn() called from Future::poll() not executed at the time of execution?

Tags: rust, async-await, future

I'm calling an `async fn()` in `Future::poll()` but the `.await` statement and the code behind it is not executed at the time of execution.

```rust
use futures::FutureExt;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct Person<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    age: i32,
}

impl<'a> Future for Person<'a> {
    type Output = i32;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut this = self.project();
        *this.age += 10;

        let mut fut1 = fn1();
        let pinfut1 = Pin::new(&mut fut1);
        //let pinfut1 = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut fut1) };
        pinfut1.poll(cx)
    }
}

fn fn1() -> impl Future<Output = i32> + Unpin {
    async {
        dbg!("sleep start!"); // execute here!
        async_std::task::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5)).await; //  <--- blocked here ?
        dbg!("sleep done!"); // Never execute here！
        123
    }
    .boxed()
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Person {
        name: "jack",
        age: Default::default(),
    };
    async_std::task::block_on(async {
        let a = p1.await;
        dbg!(a); // Never execute here!
    });
    std::thread::park();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6585cddc293e0e2e67c8a65d13d079ff)

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "test-poll"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["xx <xx@xx.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
async-std="1.8.0"
pin-project="0.4.6"
futures=""
```

Comment: This post has playground is a little clearer, just that post because of my reasons, ran off the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time your `Person` future is polled, you create a brand new `fn1` future:

```rust
let mut fut1 = fn1();
```

That future waits for 5 seconds, then wakes the executor, which polls `Person`, which then creates a brand new `fn1` future, which waits for 5 seconds...

See [How to implement a Future or Stream that polls an async fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61295176/155423) for instructions on how to do this correctly (although I agree that you probably *don't* want to do this in the first place).